# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sql://localhost:3306/Hospital

Tags: java, mysql

So this was an attempt to connect mySQl database to my Java program and display the results. But the java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found ERROR is shown. I am not entirely sure what the problem is.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class MyDBConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:sql://localhost:3306/HospitalManagementSystem";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from HospitalManagement");

            while(resultSet.next()){
                System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1) + "  " + resultSet.getString(2) + "  " + resultSet.getInt(3) + "  " + resultSet.getString(4)+ "  " + resultSet.getString(5));

                connection.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is showing as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=51805:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\johan\HospitalManagement\out\production\HospitalManagement;C:\Users\johan\Downloads\mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar MyDBConnect

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sql://localhost:3306/HospitalManagementSystem

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Could Someone explain what went wrong

Comment: `mysql  -uroot --password= HospitalManagementSystem -e "show tables"` says what? (Much better to use your own user name and have a password btw)

Comment: _No suitable driver found_ means that Java cannot find a class that knows how to handle the URL that you supplied, i.e. `jdbc:sql://localhost:3306/HospitalManagementSystem`. By the way, you no longer need to explicitly load the [JDBC] driver class. In other words, you can remove the following line from your code: `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");` Also, as a general rule for all Java code, your `catch` block should contain the following: `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: My guess is that you have an error in your URL. I think it should be: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HospitalManagementSystem` In other words `mysql` rather than just `sql`.